# Rally Apps sdk 1: release dashboard

Tags: rally

Newbie. In the Rally Apps Catalog there is a Release Dashboard report I would like to display outside of Rally. I would like to combine that report/dashboard with two other standard report in a html page. ie I would like to create a dashboard type reports using Rally Sdk.  is it possible?

how can I create my own charts using the sdk?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.  Please contact Rally support concerning gaining access to loginKey functionality to enable running reports externally (in a wiki, sharepoint portal, etc.).

Comment: - used the LoginKey in the source code but it did not work.  the source code did not reference the Rally Apps SDK so I figured that was why it did not work with the LoginKey. There was a Mashup reference instead.  I want to be able to use the sdk to recreate the Release Dashboard chart.